# How do I mock this Rowmapper class in java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jdbc, junit, mockito

I can't seem to mock the OfferRowMapper class since it's creating a new instance within the method. I can't make OfferRowMapper I am trying to unit test this method here:

```
    @Override
    public List<OfferDetailDTO> getOfferDetails(String programType, Integer pageNo, Integer pageSize) {
        OfferRowMapper rowMapper = new OfferRowMapper();
        try {
            jdbcTemplate.query(query, rowMapper, new Object[]{programType, pageNo, pageSize});
            log.info(Logger.EVENT_UNSPECIFIED, String.format(Constants.INFO_109, programType, rowMapper.getData().size()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(Logger.EVENT_FAILURE, String.format(ErrorCodeConstants.ERROR_107, programType, e.getMessage()));
            throw new GenericException(e.getMessage());
        }
        return rowMapper.getData();
    }
```

This is my unit test so far, which is failing since rowMapper.getData() returns nothing since it isn't able to be mocked.

```
    @Test
    void testGetOfferDetails_thenSuccess() {
        // mock
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(JDBCDataAccessLayer, "query", "select query");
        OfferRowMapper offerRowMapper = Mockito.mock(OfferRowMapper.class);
        OfferDetailDTO OfferDetailDTO = new OfferDetailDTO();
        OfferDetailDTO.setOmsOfferId(2506763L);
        OfferDetailDTO.setPriceText("$5.20 Each");
        OfferDetailDTO.setProgramTypeCd("W");
        OfferDetailDTO.setHeadlineTxt("Gefilte Fish");
        List<OfferDetailDTO> OfferDetailDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
        OfferDetailDTOList.add(OfferDetailDTO);
        Mockito.when(JDBCDataAccessLayer.createOfferRowMapper()).thenReturn(offerRowMapper);
        Mockito.doNothing().when(jdbcTemplate).query(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(OfferRowMapper.class), Mockito.any(Object.class));

        // call and assert
        List<OfferDetailDTO> OfferDetailDTOS = JDBCDataAccessLayer.getOfferDetails("W", 0, 30);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(OfferDetailDTOS);
        Assertions.assertEquals(1, OfferDetailDTOS.size());
        Assertions.assertEquals("W", OfferDetailDTOS.get(0).getProgramTypeCd());
        Assertions.assertEquals("Gefilte Fish", OfferDetailDTOS.get(0).getHeadlineTxt());
        Assertions.assertEquals("$5.20 Each", OfferDetailDTOS.get(0).getPriceText());
        Assertions.assertEquals(2506763L, OfferDetailDTOS.get(0).getOmsOfferId());
    }
```

I cannot use constructor injection for the rowmapper since it implements RowCallbackHandler

```
public class OfferRowMapper implements RowCallbackHandler {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(Constants.DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
    private List<OfferDetailDTO> rsMappedRows = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        OfferDetailDTO OfferDetailDTO = new OfferDetailDTO();
        OfferDetailDTO.setOmsOfferId(rs.getLong("oms_offer_id"));
        OfferDetailDTO.setProgramTypeCd(rs.getString("program_type_cd"));
        OfferDetailDTO.setDisclaimer(rs.getString("disclaimer"));
        OfferDetailDTO.setPriceText(rs.getString("price_txt"));
        OfferDetailDTO.setHeadlineTxt(rs.getString("headline_txt"));
        OfferDetailDTO.setHeadline2Txt(rs.getString("headline2_txt"));
        OfferDetailDTO.setLand(rs.getString("land"));
        OfferDetailDTO.setSpace(rs.getString("space"));
        OfferDetailDTO.setSlot(rs.getString("slot"));
        rsMappedRows.add(OfferDetailDTO);
    }

    public List<OfferDetailDTO> getData() {
        return rsMappedRows;
    }
}
```

can somebody guide me on how to test this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer

You will never be able to mock the `OfferRowMapper`
that is used within the `getOfferDetails` method if you keep the code:
`OfferRowMapper rowMapper = new OfferRowMapper();` in the `getOfferDetails` method.

### Some Solutions

In order to mock the `OfferRowMapper`,
you must do one of the following:

1. Pass the OfferRowMapper as a parameter to the `getOfferDetails` method.
   With this technique,
   you would create a mock of `OfferRowMapper` in your unit test and pass it in.
2. Move the OfferRowMapper out of the method and make it a class field that is used within the `getOfferDetails` method.
   With this technique,
   you would create a mock of `OfferRowMapper` in your unit test and set the class variable to this mock.
3. Create a factory method, perhaps within the class, that creates the  `OfferRowMapper`.
   With this technique,
   you would stub this method within your unit test and have it return a mock object.